# Combination 20 amp dbl breaker tripping when oven is in heating cycle

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven

We renovated a kitchen and installed a GE Profile single wall oven rated at 20 amps, I fed this with a 45 foot run of 10-3 nm cable to allow for oven substitution down the road and also I already had it. The circuit is protected by an Eaton double pole 20 amp combination breaker.  While setting up and testing the oven the breaker trips when the oven is just beginning the heating cycle.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you sure you read the nameplate correctly? That seems low for an oven.

Comment: Model number of the oven?

Comment: I would agree with the comment that sounds low I don’t think I have ever wired any oven under 30 amps.

Comment: By "combination breaker" you mean a combination AFCI, correct? And yes, what make and model is the oven?  Also, is your CAFCI BR (wide, black handle) or CH (skinny, tan handle)?

Comment: When you say "rated at 20 amps", where are you getting that, exactly?  What do the oven's instructions have to say about breaker and wire size?  (remember 110.3(B) you must follow labeling and instructions).  That's why we want the model number, we'll go look that stuff up.